# Jolt to merge json objects in array

Tags: json, jolt

I need help in jolt transformation to merge multiple json objects in one json object with similar keys in array.

**Input**

```json
[
  {
    "requests": [
      "?a=10&b=20&c=Name"
    ]
  },
  {
    "requests": [
      "?a=20&b=30&c=Age"
    ]
  }
]
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "requests" : [ "?a=10&b=20&c=Name", "?a=20&b=30&c=Age" ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&1" // &1 replicates the literal "requests" grabbing after going 1 level up the tree
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi @Datadev , best wishes. Can you please upvote as well, since only upvoting increases the score of tag badge, thanks in advance.